# A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:　I wanna resolve this Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently developing the application like a making blog service.
Then, I added some functions that could edit and delete the blog.
In order to add the function that could delete the blog that has comment object,
I wrote the code "@OneToMany(mappedBy="blog",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)"
then, it couldn't be editing the blog. The Error occurred.
Please tell me where to modify. I'm a beginner.

Java 8
spring boot version 2.2.12

```
A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: jp.kuroda.sampleBlog.model.Blog.comments; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:

at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1467.save(Unknown Source)
    at jp.kuroda.sampleBlog.service.BlogService.editBlog(BlogService.java:54)
    at jp.kuroda.sampleBlog.controller.PersonController.editBlog(PersonController.java:100)
```

```
@Entity   
@Data  
public class Blog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;  

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="blog",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Comment> comments; 
}

@Entity  
@Data  
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="blog_id")
    private Blog blog;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
}
  
@Service
public class BlogService {
    public void editBlog(Blog blog) { 
        blog.setPostDateTime(LocalDateTime.now()
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")));
        blogRepository.save(blog);
    }

    public void deleteBlog(Blog blog) {
        blogRepository.deleteById(blog.getId());
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private BlogService blogService;

    @GetMapping("/blog/{blogId}/edit")
    public String editBlog(@PathVariable("blogId")Blog blog,Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("base64image",blog.getBase64_str());
        model.addAttribute("blog",blog);
        return"person/create";
    }

    @PostMapping("/blog/{blogId}/edit")
    public String editBlog(@Valid Blog blog,BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return"person/create";
        }
        blogService.editBlog(blog);
        return"redirect:/person/edit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing any operations/modifications to `Comments` of the `Blog`  before you call the `editBlog` with unsaved  `Comments`?

Comment: Mayby no I amn't. This is the code og comment.`public Comment getComment(Blog blog,Person person) {
  Comment comment=new Comment();
  comment.setBlog(blog);
  comment.setPerson(person);
  return comment;
 }
 public Comment createComment(Comment comment) {
  comment.setPostDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")));
  commentRepository.save(comment);
  return comment;
 }
 public void deleteComment(Comment comment) {
  commentRepository.deleteById(comment.getId());
 }`